# How to make VLC act as a Kiosk

Tags: linux, command-line, vlc-media-player

I'm thinking of using VLC in a Kiosk type application I'm designing, and I have a couple questions.

I need VLC to start in fullscreen mode (easily done) but not allow the users to open new files or anything. Seeing as this is for a Kiosk I need to lockdown the system behind the application. After the video is done, VLC should simply quit and exit. A user could be able to prematurely kill VLC (Alt+F4) which is also fine.

Can this be done? Would I need a script calling VLC to add extra features instead of calling it right from my application? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have to use Windows? I found a great ubuntu kiosk project that I was able to modify to fit my needs pretty easily if you don't mind using ubuntu...

Comment: Hmm. Maybe you don't want the "full" VLC, but rather something like [`ffplay.exe`](http://www.wu.ece.ufl.edu/projects/wirelessVideo/project/realTimeCoding/buildingffplayforwindows.htm) which is invoked by the command line, displays a video, and then finishes. No controls, nothing else.

Comment: Whatever the solution, I need it to be somewhat cross platform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if VLC would support this directly, but if you're using a Unix environment, then you could execute vlc with

```
chroot /sterile/directory/media-files vlc <options>
```

so that vlc can only see the files within the `/sterile/directory/media-files` directory. Then, if a user opened any dialogues, they could still yet only interact with the files that VLC knew about.

Comment: This is good for a Unix environment but I need something that would also in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `cvlc` with option `--fullscreen` which will act like a kiosk. The command is:

```
cvlc --fullscreen mediafile
```

Hope this will help you.